# Download Service stop download 50%

Tags: java, android

I have app for download file apk 20 MB from the server, but problem download process stops at 50% or 60% some time and file get the wrong size and can't install app . any help ? I have tried some solutions like adding
set Connect Timeout .

this my code

```
       public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    ResultReceiver receiver = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);

        String fileExtenstion = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(String.valueOf(url));

        String name_file = URLUtil.guessFileName(String.valueOf(url), null, fileExtenstion);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Appt/" + name_file);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
    resultData.putInt("progress" ,100);
    receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
}
```

Comment: 1) Are there any client-side exceptions / stacktraces?  2) Check the server-side logs for relevant info. 3) Check that the server-side (or the network) doesn't implement some kind of download limits.

Comment: A client-side Connect timeout would not cause this behavior.  A Read timeout *might*, but if it did there would be a stacktrace.